# Is this good practice to use a single templateUrl for multiple states in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular frame work. I just want to know the way I am working is good or not ? If no what is the solution.

My requirement is if I login as admin I have one profile page
If I login as a staff the then I have same profile(same html) but differnt header ,sidemenu, footer is there

So I Create state like using $staeprovider

```
.state('adminHeader', {
    url:'/adminHeader',
    templateUrl:'adminHeader.html'
})
 .state('adminHeader.sidebar', {
    url:'/sidebar',
    templateUrl:'sidebar.html'
})
.state('adminHeader.sidebar.profile', {
    url:'/profile',
    templateUrl:'profile.html'
})
.state('staffHeader', {
    url:'/staffHeader',
    templateUrl:'staffHeader.html'
})
.state('staffHeader.staffprofile', {
    url:'/staffHeader',
    templateUrl:'profile.html'
});
```

I am using **profile.html** for two differnt states. Then controoler will be common for both. Is this best practie. Is am getting scope issues any where.

If not please suggest to fix this problem.

For Admin, stff there is different headers, sidemenu. thats why I designed both in different states and different htmls.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: As far as you are using for same data using same templates for multiple states is fine..

Comment: What scope issues are you getting?

Comment: Just now I am implementing this structure in my project.. I am clarifying that the this is good approach or not

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you that, you should breakdown your application page into small components. Which would be independently responsible for it own role. If needed they will communicate via service. I'd say that you can take out below list of `component` inside your application.

1. Header
2. Footer
3. Sidebar
4. Main content

1st three component are going to be stay the same as that for almost all state of your application. So better create a `abstract`(means this state will not accessible directly) state with `header`, `footer` & `sidebar` component. Each part of your application will reside in its own named `ui-view`.

Thereafter the `main-content` view be replaced by child state of `admin` which could be `admin.dash`/`admin.staff`/`admin.profile`.

**Config**

```
.state('admin', {
  url: '/admin',
  abstract: true,
  controller: 'adminController',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'admin.html',
      controller: 'adminCtrl'
    },
    'header': {
      templateUrl: 'header.html',
      controller: 'headerCtrl'
    },
    'footer': {
      templateUrl: 'footer.html',
      controller: 'footerCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('admin.profile', {
  url: '/admin',
  views: {
    'main-content@admin': {
      templateUrl: 'profile.html',
      controller: 'profileCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('admin.dash', {
  url: '/dash',
  views: {
    'main-content@admin': {
      templateUrl: 'dash.html',
      controller: 'dashCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

And then the special part is when it comes to staff state header will be change via staff state.

```
.state('admin.staff', {
    url:'/staff',
    views: {
       'main-content@admin': {
          templateUrl: 'staff.html',
          controller: 'staffCtrl'
       },
       'header@': {
          templateUrl: 'staffHeader.html',
          controller: 'staffHeaderCtrl'
       }
    }
})
```

If you are implementing it with Angular 1.5+, you can create a component for each part of application & state code reduced down to below with reusable component architecture.

```
.state('admin', {
    url:'/admin',
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'adminController'
    views: {
       '': { component: 'admin' },
       'header': { component: 'header' },
       'footer': { component: 'footer' }
    }
})
.state('admin.profile', {
    url:'/admin',
    views: {
       'main-content@admin': { component: 'profile' }
    }
})
.state('admin.dash', {
    url:'/dash',
    views: {
       'main-content@admin': { component: 'dash' }
    }
})
.state('admin.staff', {
    url:'/staff',
    views: {
       'main-content@admin': { component: 'staff' },
       'header@': {  component: 'staff-header'}
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you Please explain me in clear(with states code)

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar writing more, I'm on the way to add state code and explaining in a minute

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar checkout updated answer ;) Let me know if you don't understand it.

Comment: How to load this views in html(ui-views)  and the css for admin , staff will different. If I use admin.staff staes like one stae css will effect another

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar what do you mean by CSS will effect another?

Comment: Please Edit this answer in Plunker or Js Fiddle.